# Is there a way to install scripts on different servers but still on same domain?

Tags: php, nginx, hosting, load-balancing, web-hosting

I'm looking for a way to install scripts on different servers, but still using the same domain.  Not subdomain.

Is it possible?

eg.

```
Server 1 - Forum script - installed on http://domain.com/forum

Server 2 - Wordpress Script - installed on http://domain.com/blog
```

I find that large business entities must have their application services distributed or segmented into different servers.

Doing it via subdomain is straight forward, but how do I deploy various channels/services under the same primary domain?

Comment: Look for "transparent proxy" or even some hardware solution like a load balancing system. That's more a question of administration and equipment, not really programming, except you intend to develop your own proxy software.

Comment: use proxy_pass on nginx or apache

Comment: If using `proxy_pass`, does `php session` & `cookies` remained intact?  Is HAProxy a possible solution?